# While migrating D6 to D7, should sites folder be replaced?

Tags: migrations

I am trying to migrate Drupal 6.29 to 7.22. Part of migration I have deleted all files & directories except sites in D6 site. Now I downloaded Drupal 7.22. D7 version also has sites folder, so do I need to replace sites folder or not?
In documentation I read like while copying the sites folder which files need automatically will be replaced, when I am copying sites it is asking for replace or not. Totally confused, can anyone help on this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: May I ask why you would update to a very old release of Drupal 7? The latest version is 7.43, 7.22 is from 2013.

Comment: @ Micheal - Thanks for your response,Just i am checking with 7.22,thats it. hope procedure will be same for 7.22&7.43 .

Comment: Once  worked for 7.22 i will go  far 7.43...

Answer (score 0):

The [upgrade documentation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/UPGRADE.txt?id=refs/heads;id2=7.x) is quite precise about this step:

> 2. Update to the latest available version of Drupal 6.x
>
> [...]
>
> 9. Remove all old core files and directories, except for the 'sites' directory
>      and any custom files you added elsewhere.  [...]
> 10. If you uninstalled any modules, remove them from the sites/all/modules and
>       other sites/*/modules directories. Leave other modules in place, even though
>       they are incompatible with Drupal 7.x.
> 11. Download the latest Drupal 7.x release from http://drupal.org to a
>       directory outside of your web root. Extract the archive and copy the files
>       into your Drupal directory.

```
 cp -R drupal-x.y/* drupal-x.y/.htaccess /path/to/your/installation
```

Executing the above shell command, will copy all the content of the drupal-x.y directory recursively to your installation directory. This will silently overwrite all files in your installation **that are also** in the drupal-x.y directory and create directories that are not already there. If there is a directory in both, say sites/default/files, only those files will be overwritten that are also in the source, and **no files will be deleted** from a directory, that is why you had to remove the core files in step 9. This is the default behaviour of `cp`. If you want to know more about how this works you [could read](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) `man cp`.

If you are not on unix or you don't have shell access to your server, you have to emulate this behavior (at the moment I cannot think about a copy function either on Windows or Mac that behaves differently, e.g. replacing a folder with files inside with an empty folder), because it is the recommended one, using the admin interface you have.